# XPATH to check on a specific text within a node

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this as a node to parse:

```
<h3 class="atag">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">
      <span class="btag">text to be ignored</span>
         </a>
           <span class="ctag">text to be checked</span>
</h3>
```

I'm gonna need to extract "http://www.example.com" but not the part text to to be ignored; I also need to check that if ctag contains text to be checked.

I came up with this but it seems it doesn't do the job.

```
response.xpath("//h3/a/@*[not(self::span)]").extract()
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to just select href from 'a' tag, use @href.
To also check, whether the ctag contains some text, I think you can use code like this:

```
'//h3[contains(span[@class="ctag"]/text(), "text to be checked")]/a/@href'
```

This would check whether there is a span with "text to be checked" inside given h3 block. If the text exists, the 'www.example.com' would be found, otherwise there would be an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this XPath? :

```
//h3/a[following-sibling::span[@class='ctag' and .='text to be checked']/@href
```

above XPath get `<a>` tag that followed by `<span class="ctag">` containing value of `"text to be checked"`, then return `href` attribute from the previously mentioned `<a>` tag.